# Joomla get values from StdClass

Tags: php, joomla, get, stdclass

Little qeustion here, since i'm having troubles with retreiving my data from Joomla component.

I have two objects within my query result, now i am echoing it like this:

```
$test[0]->ID_pkey
$test[0]->SnelstartID

$test[1]->ID_pkey
$test[1]->SnelstartID
```

What i want is that he returns everything at once ( reminds me of windows song)

Can you guys help me? little stuck in here
I use this inside of Joomla, so maybe some experts for a Joomla solution?

I think a foreach or a while would do the job, but getting syntaxs errors all over the place, also a `var_dump` to help you guys out:

> array(2) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#224 (9) { ["ID_pkey"]=> string(1) "1" ["SnelstartID"]=> string(10) "1578324568" ["Type"]=> string(4) "ADSL" ["Desc"]=> string(26) "Dit is een ADSL abbonoment" ["Up"]=> string(1) "5" ["Down"]=> string(1) "7" ["Img"]=> string(16) "images/phone.png" ["Inkoop"]=> string(4) "5.15" ["Prijs"]=> string(4) "9.99" } [1]=> object(stdClass)#231 (9) { ["ID_pkey"]=> string(1) "2" ["SnelstartID"]=> string(10) "1574648494" ["Type"]=> string(4) "FTTC" ["Desc"]=> string(26) "Dit is een FTTC abbonoment" ["Up"]=> string(1) "8" ["Down"]=> string(2) "10" ["Img"]=> string(16) "images/phone.png" ["Inkoop"]=> string(4) "8.15" ["Prijs"]=> string(4) "9.15" } }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this.

```
foreach($youarray_result as $key=>$value){

    echo $value->ID_pkey;
    echo $value->SnelstartID;
}
```

this may solve your problem!